# Shortcut to move shape without connectors in Visio

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, microsoft-visio, connector, move

In Visio, is there a shortcut key that will let me move shape without any connectors attached to it. As in, click and hold mouse button while pressing a key, drag the shape and leave the connectors in place. Flip/rotate the shape then put the shape back.

Other programs, like circuit simulators, will let you Right mouse click and hold, move the component, flip/rotate, then put it back.

I often need to flip a shape, but first I have to disconnect all the connectors. Some are simple and have only 2 connectors but many of my shapes have lots more. This takes up too much time.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest method to disconnect a shape is to cut and re-insert it
(Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V).
You may wish to ensure that the Visio option is not checked to delete the
connectors when the shape is deleted, if you wish to keep the connectors.

For more elaborate methods, see Microsoft's article
[Glue or unglue connectors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/glue-or-unglue-connectors-c55370ae-a3c3-4468-9232-b32604f7252f).

You may also lock a connector in its place by selecting it and in
the Format tab, the Arrange group, select Lock. See the article
[How To Make Connectors Not Interfere In Visio](https://www.process.st/how-to/make-connectors-not-interfere-in-visio/).

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. However none of the suggestions viable for me. Dnd some are, no longer available? CUT and Paste is a worse option in my case. I am trying to keep the shape count as low as possible. Every time a shape is cut and pasted back it does not keep the same shape ID. I have a shape called "Global", and that shape controls many things like if a switch turns on, many other shapes get sent get sent a formula to change Fillpattern, Linepattern, Angle, W/H, and others. So if the ID gets changed then I still have to do more work, getting them all back.  Lock doesn't exist

Comment: Lock doesn't exist, at least in my version of Visio. It is missing and can't find it anywhere. Spent the time between your reply till now looking for it. "Next, go to the Format tab and in the Arrange group, select Lock." I have no Format Tab and Arrange group there is no Lock option. Running Visio Pro 2021.

Comment: This text might relate to a format tab that appears when an object is selected and may be different per object type. I no longer have Visio on my computer, so I cannot experiment myself.

Comment: Well I tried other objects and nothing appears. It says specifically "to lock the connector" but it tried anyway. No luck.

Comment: The Format tab is where you see a style gallery for the selected connector.

Comment: ok again there is no Format Tab anywhere in my visio. Will you post an image of yours and where it is. I is not even in the list when customizing the ribbon. I have checked in all of the tabs and there is not lock function.

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have Visio on my computer.

Comment: Have you downvoted my answer ?